# How do I interpret this set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

$$\{x \mid x \in D, P(x)\}.$$
Is the above set read as "all x such that x is in D and the property P(x) is satisfied"? Also, is this set the same as
$$\{x \in D \mid P(x)\}.$$

Comment: Unless your book has some strange conventions yes and yes (and this is the proper notation).

Comment: Yes, the comma is used as "and".

Comment: There's a detail missing. "**The set of** all $x$ such that ...”.

Comment: Also, I think many people would read it in the more concise way "The set of all x such that x is in D and P(x)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "all x such that x is in D and the property P(x) is satisfied"

Assuming that we are working with the standard notation, the answer is **yes**. It may help to think of the comma in $\{x \mid x \in D, P(x)\}$ as a way of saying "and".

> Also, is this set the same as $\{x \in D \mid P(x)\}$?

**Yes**, it is indeed the same.